# Using a variable in D3 data method to pull JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

So I'm pulling data from JSON code, but I want the data I pull to be a variable (that I would let the user define by using select menus) and not a direct reference.

I was just wondering if it was possible for what follows the 'd.' to be a variable? If not I would love to hear some proposed workarounds. Here is an example of a solution along the lines of what I'm hoping to achieve.

```
canvas.selectAll("circle")
.data(finaldataset)
.enter();

var userBuiltVariable1 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;
var userBuiltVariable2 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;
var userBuiltVariable3 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;

circles.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.userBuiltVariable1})
.attr("cy", function(d){ return d.userBuiltVariable2})
.attr("r", function(d){return d.userBuiltVariable3});
```

The JSON code looks like so;

```
"Country":"Wales",
"BoyEveryday1102":"0.9",
"BoyOnceWeek1102":"1.2",
"BoyLessThanOW1102":"1.9",
"BoyDont1102":"96.0"
```

this shorthand means Gender - How often they smoke - how old they are - what year the data was taken. So the second line is showing Boys, who smoke everyday, aged 11, in the year 2002. Other examples include "GirlOnceWeek1510" or "GirlDont1306" so this variable would be built by the user with select menus. Any help greatly appreciated - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is quite easily done. The solution would be nothing to do with d3 per se, just Javascript basics.

If you have a Javascript object, there are a number of ways you can query its properties.

The first, and most common one, is the dot notation, which you are already using in your code above.

```
var myObject = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log( 'dot notation', foo.bar );
```

Another, less common opne, is to use square brackets. With this, you may use any variable (but it only makes sense to use strings).

```
var myObject = { foo: 'bar' };
var myProperty = 'foo';
console.log( 'square brackets', foo[myProperty] );
```

Now applying this to your example code:

```
var userBuiltVariable1 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;
var userBuiltVariable2 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;
var userBuiltVariable3 = someStringMadeViaSelectMenus;

circles.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr("cx", function(d){ return d[userBuiltVariable1]})
.attr("cy", function(d){ return d[userBuiltVariable2]})
.attr("r", function(d){return d[userBuiltVariable3]});
```

... should give you what you want.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll probably be using the latter option as I just feel more comfortable with it and I will be using a string. I'm using this to build a visualisation for the World Health Organisation, I'll be sure to show you the final product! Many thanks again

Comment: @user2279573 No worries, happy to help. Yes please, post a link to your visualisation when you are done!